# R Data.Table Cut Data Into Groups And Label

Tags: r, data.table, cut

```
data1=data.frame("Score"=c(1,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6),
"Group"=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
"Group1"=c('Cat','Cat','Fox','Fox','Fox','Fox','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog'))
```

I have 'data1' with just score. I wish to add Group and Group 1. The rules are:

If 0 <= score <= 1, Group = 1, GrouopLabel = Cat

If 2 <= score <= 4, Group = 2, GrouopLabel = Fox

If 5 <= score <= 10, Group = 3, GrouopLabel = Dog

Comment: The second value of 'Score' is 3, so, it should belong to 'Fox'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cut` to create the 'Group', then based on the numeric index of 'Group', replace the values to 'Cat', 'Fox', 'Dog' in 'Group1'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[, Group := as.integer(cut(Score, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 4, 10)))][,
         Group1 := c('Cat', 'Fox', 'Dog')[Group]][]
```

Comment: ! perfect! i notice when i do this it updates 'data1' but also prints out the data.

Comment: @bvowe it prints because I used `[]` at the end